# Upload to random server from original server SSH

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, rsync, scp

I currently have 5 servers, 1 upload server (ftp.example.com) and 4 storage servers (fs#.example.com). I'm currently looking for a way to send files from my upload server to one of the storage servers by random.

Upload file.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt to ftp.example.com

file.txt -> fs1.example.com

file2.txt -> fs4.example.com

file3.txt -> fs2.example.com

I've been looking at rsync, rclone and scp but I can't find an option where it would select the login details of a server from an array or .txt file etc. I was wondering if anyone could suggest a way to do this ? Ideally this would be done via a text file which I can update with additional servers or remove servers depending on capacity etc.

Working example I made using bash.

file location: `/root/`

```
HOSTS=(root@host_ip_one root@host_ip_two root@host_ip_three root@host_ip_four)

find /root/*  -mmin +1 -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec realpath {} \; -exec sshpass -p PASWORD rsync --remove-source-files {} ${HOSTS[RANDOM%${#HOSTS[@]}]}:/ \;
```

I can then run this on as a cronjob every 5 minutes or so and it will automatically take files that have completed upload (by checking last modify time was over a minute ago) and then logging into rsync with a random host.

The downfall with this is that it requires all hosts to use the same password.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a bash script of some sort in order to read a file and randomly select a storage server from it. To minimize human intervention, though, I'd suggest setting up [SSH keys](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/) with all of your servers, then editing your `~/.ssh/config` file on your host machine to include entries for all of your servers. For instance:

```
Host storage_server_1
    HostName fs1.example.com
    User admin
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Host storage_server_2
    HostName fs2.example.com
    User john
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

...
```

Instead of host names, I'd write the "Host" value of each server on each line of your input file. Then, if you're using bash 4.0, something like the following could be of use:

```bash
storage_server_list=/path/to/storage/server/file.txt

# Read the list of servers into an array (assuming there's one server per line)
readarray -t server_list ${storage_server_list}

num_servers=${#server_list[@]}
random_server_idx=$(( $RANDOM % ${num_servers} ))

# Pick a random server from the array
random_server=${server_list[${random_server_idx}]}

scp some_file ${random_server}

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "scp failed" > /dev/stderr
else
    echo "scp succeeded"
fi
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more one liner, I'm not sure why I was thinking that but I took the idea of a bash script and updated my question with a working example, thanks.

Comment: @Paulamonopoly If you're concerned about all hosts using the same password, try the SSH config approach I mentioned above. You can specify different public keys; that effectively is using a new "password" for each host.